# How can I improve the design of this serialization mechanism?

Tags: c++, template, template-meta-programming

I'm working on caching library which is intended to work with all types of values.

Values are represented as instances of `value_type`: `value_type` holds a `std::vector<char>` for the raw data, and a `uint32_t` `flags` integer value which is used to indicate the format of the stored data.

I would like to make it easy for the users of the library and provided a `serialize()` method that would convert a `C++` type to a `value_type` so that instead of writing:

```
// In the line below, serialization::string is an integer constant
value_type value(serialization::string, "My string");
```

People could just write:

```
value_type value = serialize("My string");
```

And somehow the `serialize()` method would *"guess"* that the associated integer flag is `serialization::string`.

I would also make it possible for an user to register his own types and conversions into the serialization mechanism.

I came up with the following code:

```
/**
 * \brief A default serializer type.
 * \tparam Type The type to serialize.
 */
template <typename Type>
struct serializer {};

/**
 * \brief The base serializer type.
 * \tparam Type The serialized type.
 * \tparam Flags The flags.
 *
 * Derive from this type to enable a new serialization.
 */
template <typename Type, value_type::flags_type Flags>
struct base_serializer
{
    /**
     * \brief The type supported by the serializer.
     */
    typedef Type type;

    /**
     * \brief The flags.
     */
    static const value_type::flags_type flags = Flags;

    static value_type serialize(const type& value)
    {
        return value_type(flags, serializer<type>::serialize_data(value));
    }

    /**
     * \brief Deserialize a value.
     * \param value The value.
     * \return The deserialized value.
     */
    static Type deserialize(const value_type& value)
    {
        if (value.flags() != flags)
        {
            throw boost::system::system_error(serialization::error::invalid_types, serialization::serialization_category(), "deserialization failed");
        }

        return serializer<type>::deserialize_data(value.data());
    }
};

/**
 * \brief Serialize a value.
 * \tparam Type The type.
 * \param value The value.
 * \return The serialized value.
 */
template <typename Type>
value_type serialize(const Type& value) { return serializer<Type>::serialize(value); }

/**
 * \brief Deserialize a value.
 * \tparam Type The type.
 * \param value The value.
 * \return The deserialized value.
 */
template <typename Type>
Type deserialize(const value_type& value) { return serializer<Type>::deserialize(value); }

/**
 * \brief A const char* serializer.
 */
template <>
struct serializer<const char*> : public base_serializer<const char*, serialization::string>
{
    static std::vector<char> serialize_data(type value)
    {
        return std::vector<char>(value, value + strlen(value));
    }
};

/**
 * \brief An overload.
 * \param value A C-string.
 * \return The serialized value.
 */
value_type serialize(const char* value) { return serializer<const char*>::serialize(value); }

/**
 * \brief A std::string serializer.
 */
template <>
struct serializer<std::string> : public base_serializer<std::string, serialization::string>
{
    static std::vector<char> serialize_data(type value)
    {
        return std::vector<char>(value.begin(), value.end());
    }

    static type deserialize_data(const std::vector<char>& value)
    {
        return type(value.begin(), value.end());
    }
};
```

Do you guys see any improvement ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an internal traits type to reduce redundancy and complexity.

```
template< typename serialized >
struct serialize_traits; // no implementation of general case

enum class serialize_style {
    string,
    integral
};

typedef std::vector< char > serial_type; // consider std::string instead

template<>
struct serialize_traits< char * > {
    static const serialize_style style = serialize_style::string;
};

template<>
struct serialize_traits< std::string > {
    static const serialize_style style = serialize_style::string;
};

// Since serializer has no state, I broke this into a free function.
/* It works with both char * and std::string, but uses std::enable_if
   to hide itself unless you specify in serialize_traits that it will work. */

template < typename serialized >
typename std::enable_if< serialize_traits< serialized >::style == serialize_style::string,
serial_type >::type
serialize( serialized const &in ) {
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    return serial_type( begin( in ), end( in ) );
}
```

I need to go so I'll post this now… not tested.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time of posting this. I will try it and keep you posted :)

Comment: Ah, it will fail because `begin` and `end` are not defined for `char*` strings. But you get the idea… hope this ultimately helps.